# How many axes of symmetry for a skewed cuboid?

Tags: group-theory, geometry, symmetry

How many axes of **rotational** symmetry are there for the following object? Also, is there an algorithmic procedure for finding the axes of rotational symmetry for a general 3D object?

Here are all the objects I am interested in: https://p3d.in/u/juliuscaesar/p883t

It is probably difficult to communicate verbally the axes. But if you download the associated STL files, you can see the XYZ coordinate frame (e.g. using [Meshlab](https://www.meshlab.net/) software) and thus define the axises in this XYZ frame.

Comment: A picture is worth a thousand words

Comment: About your last question: what do you mean by a "general 3D object" and how would you describe it mathematically for this supposed algorithm to work

Comment: Posted a link with examples of which ones I want

Comment: Theres an algorithm here: but it seems complicated and not exact (because it relies on sampling and checking): https://l.messenger.com/l.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fciteseerx.ist.psu.edu%2Fviewdoc%2Fdownload%3Fdoi%3D10.1.1.102.4853%26rep%3Drep1%26type%3Dpdf&h=AT1gYMM2TiBExWxsREm02pz2ztrqCM3XesMAKmXfWExoUzzqnZuYhY9HKobsic4w-8aFjDUYR3evogEZp_uU0ohofO0X1eHW7YDMGXjwqymDAhGRB4xZwMaylwWaww

Comment: If someone can just tell me the axes for the objects I linked above that would also be helpful!

Comment: Fun English quirk: the plural of "axis" is "axes".